# What does "inverted index are immutable in elastic search" exactly mean?

Tags: elasticsearch, inverted-index

I was going through the online definitive guide of elastic search.

I have a question on immutability of inverted index described at following link:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/making-text-searchable.html

What will happen when a new document is added in index? Will inverted index be recreated to include details/metadata related to new document?

Will  it not impact the performance of elastic?

Comment: I am a bit confused with the documentation in the link I mentioned. I think, it is the "Segments" that represent an inverted index. When new documents are created, a new Segment is created in memory buffer. Once this Segment is commited and written into disk, it serves the purpose of Inverted index for documents belonging to this segment.

Comment: Yes, this is very close. Segments don't have to be written to disk to be searchable, but otherwise you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered towards the end of that article:

Of course, an immutable index has its downsides too, primarily the fact that it is immutable! You can’t change it. **If you want to make new documents searchable, you have to rebuild the entire index.** This places a significant limitation either on the amount of data that an index can contain, or the frequency with which the index can be updated.

This means that your old index will need to be destroyed and recreated to include the new document. Performance impact can be mitigated by clustering your data and performing the new index creation on the cold cluster then switching it to hot and then rebuilding the index on the now cold cluster.

Comment: Seems, for a realtime scenario or for time series data, where new documents are added in elastic very frequently, inverted index will be re-created very frequently ? Will elastic perform better in realtime scenarios ?

Comment: I think, the concept of Segments is answer to my query. Following is the link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/dynamic-indices.html

Comment: So essentially the dynamicly updated indices are segments of inverted immutable indices. Going this route is fine until you have too many segments then I would recommend the hot swap method I mentioned above and deleting all indices and making one inverse immutable index. Depending on your rate of new documents this could be monthly, semi-monthly or yearly.

Comment: Please remove this answer and the comment — the information is plain wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When you add new documents to an index, all the documents written within 1 second (default value — you can increase it, but you really shouldn't set it to 0) are written to a (Lucene) segment. That segment will be in memory first and will be flushed to disk later on.

If you update a document, the original version will be marked as deleted and a new document will be created (batched together with other documents within 1s into a segment).

Every segment has its own inverted index(es) and as soon as it's in memory, it is searchable.

Eventually, Elasticsearch will do a merge and combine multiple segments into one. During this step the deleted and replaced (old version of an update) documents will be removed as well. You don't have to call a force merge in general — Elasticsearch is very good at figuring out when it should do that on its own.

This provides a very good performance balance in general. If you don't need to find your documents immediately, a common performance tweak is to set the refresh interval to 30s or a similar value.

PS: Changing existing data will require you to reindex your documents — there's an API for that. Reindexing data is common, especially for search use cases.